# Is there a more radical approach against copyright than copyleft?

Tags: copyleft, freedoms

Up until recently I thought that [copyleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft#:%7E:text=Copyleft%20is%20the%20practice%20of,works%20created%20from%20that%20property.) supporters totally reject the concepts of [copyright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright) and [content licensing](https://insights.newscred.com/content-licensing-the-ultimate-guide/#:%7E:text=Content%20licensing%20is%20a%20legal,across%20desktop%20and%20mobile%20platforms.) but now I know that they don't totally reject these and their main goal is to promote the usage of content licenses which *reduce copyrights amount to a possible minimum*.

Is there a more radical approach against copyright than copyleft (such that goes one step further to reject any kind of copyright AND/OR content license)?

Comment: Public domain dedications are radical in a very different way than copyleft. But it doesn't really make sense to say that they're *more* radical than copyleft.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to reject the notion of copyrights and licenses, but that quickly runs into practical problems with the law.

In all countries that have ratified the Berne convention on copyrights (which is nearly all of them), copyright law stipulates that as soon as you write down your thoughts, then that record is protected by copyrights to the highest extent. There is nothing you need to do to get copyright protection and even nothing that can prevent it. The only exception is if you are writing something that is explicitly called out in the law to not be covered by copyright protection<sup>1</sup>.

As copyright protection is automatic, the only way around it is to grant a license to others to perform actions that are otherwise reserved to the copyright owner, or to disclaim all rights and to dedicate your work explicitly to the public domain (which is not possible in all jurisdictions).

The first option would be contrary to the stated intention of rejecting copyrights and licenses. The second option might work, but I am not sure how well you could build a community/movement around it. It will not prevent the "believers in copyrights" from using your code, because code in the public domain is free to use for all.

---

<sub>[1]: Those exceptions are typically government documents intended to be widely circulated and copied, like law texts</sub>